# How to call a script in a select statement in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, select

Sounds like quite a convoluted question, but it's really not. I'm busy building a menu in a bash script, and as part of the case statement I am trying to call another script that I created a while ago which edits a file, and it's breaking. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Please choose an option: "
options=("Do this" "Do nothing")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do 
   case $opt in
      "Do this")
         read -p "Please enter the file name:`echo $'\nE9> '`" FILENAME
         getscript $FILENAME
         break
         ;;
      "Do nothing")
         break
         ;;
   esac
done
```

The error that I get from this is as follows: `getscript: command not found`

To illustrate that this works, I ran getscript from the normal command prompt and it still works:

```
$ getscript randomfilename.txt
done
```

A little more detail, in case in matters... The `getscript.sh` script in question is located in `/usr/local/bin` and I have an alias created for it in .bashrc in my current user directory, which allows me to call `getscript` only.

Please help?

Comment: Aliases aren't present in scripts.

Comment: You could resolve the problem by specifying the complete path, ie, /usr/local/bin/getscript.sh $FILENAME

Comment: I have suggested an alternate approach. Aliases its self are not supported in scripts. Please accept my answer if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biffen was correct, aliases don't seem to work in a script. So all I needed to do was add .sh on the end, and it worked perfectly... To illustrate, in case somebody needs this in the future:

```
PS3="Please choose an option: "
options=("Do this" "Do nothing")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do 
   case $opt in
      "Do this")
         read -p "Please enter the file name:`echo $'\nE9> '`" FILENAME
         getscript.sh $FILENAME
         break
         ;;
      "Do nothing")
         break
         ;;
   esac
done
```

Works like a charm :). Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines into end of `~/.bashrc`

```
function getscript() {
   /usr/local/bin/getscript.sh "$@"

}
export -f getscript
```

After this

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

This will fix the issue. If you do not have `source` package then you need to install it.

Comment: It's quite fine to run it from some other directory. The problem is trying to use an alias in a script.

Comment: Updated answer not its working with an alternate approach.

Comment: Not a very portable ‘solution’.